# Build old Csproj with Visual Studio code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2008, msbuild, omnisharp

I have an old project, created with Visual Studio 2008.
This is the header of the .csproj file.

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">
```

At this moment I'm able to build with visual studio 2008, with some pain, so I would like to change the IDE, without change the MSBuild version.

Is there a way to build it with Visual Studio Code?

Comment: You could probably hack something together using [msbuild cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022) and the `launch.json` from VS Code

Comment: I'm trying to set up Omnisharp ... but no solution at the moment

Comment: What happens when you call `msbuild MyOldProject.csproj`? Are you getting errors?